# ORA-01830: date format picture ends while downloading excel with date filter

Tags: excel, oracle, stored-procedures, datepicker

I have a functionality where I have to download excel based on `date` filter. But while downloading from Stored procedure I am getting error as

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends

Below is the logic and code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateSelection').datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '1950:2100',
                maxDate: 0
            });
        })
    </script>
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="txtDateSelection" runat="server" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />    
    
<asp:Button ID="btnDownloadInfo" runat="server" Text="Report Download" OnClick="btnDownloadInfo_Click" class="btn btn-primary downnloadReport" />    

protected void btnDownloadInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                CommonUser ObjUser = new CommonUser();
                string strDateFilter = txtDateSelection.Value;
                dtExcelData = ObjUser.GET_EXCEL_REPORT(strDateFilter);

                if (dtExcelData != null && dtExcelData.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DownloadReport(dtExcelData);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('No record found');", true);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string strErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString() + " " + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
                CommonDB.WriteLog("ERROR:" + strErrorMsg, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AIRFIBER_LOG"].ToString());
            }
        }
        
        
public DataTable GET_EXCEL_REPORT(string strDateValue)
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringAirFiber"].ConnectionString);
            DataTable dtIpColo = new DataTable();

            //strDateValue = strDateValue.ToString("");

            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GET_EXCEL_REPORT_INFO"].ToString();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_DATE", Value = strDateValue, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_CURR", OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) conn.Open();
                OracleDataAdapter daIpColo = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                daIpColo.Fill(dtIpColo);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return dtIpColo;
        }
```

Also the DB part for downloading excel.

```html
Table name:- LOS_REQUEST_MANUAL

Name                Null?    Type           
------------------- -------- ------------- 
ENB_SITE_ID                  VARCHAR2(30)  
GIS_SECTOR_ID                VARCHAR2(30)  
PMP_SAP_ID                   VARCHAR2(30)  
END_SECTOR_ID                VARCHAR2(30)  
A6_NEID             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)  
AZIMUTH                      NUMBER        
HEIGHT                       NUMBER        
VER_BEAM_WIDTH_TILT          NUMBER        
VER_BEAM_WIDTH               NUMBER        
HORIZANTAL_BEAM              NUMBER        
DISTNACE_OF_CONE             NUMBER        
SOURCE                       VARCHAR2(30)  
STATUS                       VARCHAR2(30)  
REMARKS                      VARCHAR2(250) 
MODIFIED_DATE                DATE          
USERNAME                     VARCHAR2(200)
```

Here is the nls_Date_format

`Parameter: NLS_DATE_FORMAT   value: DD-MON-RR`

Comment: The title says `ORA-01830: date format picture ends` the body says `ORA-01810: format code appears twice`. Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the actual error message that you get; the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables so we know the data-types of the columns; and the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` used by your session.

Comment: Is the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` you showed the default database parameter, or your actual session parameter, which overrides it? You should not rely on NLS settings and implicit conversion anyway; either convert explicitly with a suitable format mask, or pass the value as a date rather than as a string.

Comment: @AlexPoole: yes, it's the default database parameter. Also, can u explain how to make that conversion with date and check.